# SQL Server Management Studio - save encrypted connection string

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I configure a encrypted connection to SQL Server using Management Studio and add the connection string `TrustServerCertificate=True`, this setting will not be saved so I need to enter it every time I connect anew.

Any way to save this setting ? Thanks !

Comment: It seems like my question has been solved by Microsoft in the current version of SQL Server Management Studio 17.1. where the TrustServerCertificate=true is saved properly.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this seems to be a known SSMS issue with no known workarounds [according to Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/813973/the-ssms-connect-to-server-dialog-does-not-persist-the-settings-specified-in-the-additional-connection-parameters-tab).

Maybe a Windows macro (e.g. using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)) would be a reasonable workaround for you.